# Redcap report checkbox filter

Tags: redcap

I have a checkbox field with 5 options. I want to generate a report that only shows records where any of these 5 checkboxes have been checked.
What filter logic should I use?

I have tried using the following filter and it is not working:

`[checkbox(1)] = 1 OR [checkbox(2)] = 1 OR [checkbox(3)] = 1 OR [checkbox(4)] = 1 OR [checkbox(5)] = 1`

Comment: Issue resolved: This was the correct syntax, as below. The issue was someone had removed one of the checkbox options, rendering the report unable to execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your logic expression there @Bdl, privided your checkbox field is named `checkbox` and the choices have values 1-5.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting those choices in quotations? In other words, the logic should read as follows:

[checkbox(1)] = "1" OR [checkbox(2)] = "1" OR [checkbox(3)] = "1" OR [checkbox(4)] = "1" OR [checkbox(5)] = "1"